# Shouldn’t we say independent given the distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, independence, iid, conditional-independence

In statistics we often deal with iid random variables: independent identically distributed. But if we don’t know the distribution (say we still know the support is {0, 1}), and we get a sample x1, say it equals 1, doesn’t it give a bit of information about the other samples we can have ? Because we now know that 1 is a value with non-zero probability ? So shouldn’t we say « independent given the knowledge of their distribution » ?

Comment: I don't get your question. When variable are independent, knowing one don't give you information about the other. For sure it gives you information about the distribution (since in your case they are identically distributed).

Comment: I agree the first sample gives information about the distribution, so in turn this information about the distribution is an information about what second sample we’re going to see (we have more knowledge than at the beginning where we had no information about the distribution). That’s why I’m saying we shoud say x1 and x2 are identically distributed and independent [conditionnaly on]/[given] the distribution. (Because indeed, assuming the distribution is known, knowing x1 doesn’t give us any additional information about what x2 is going to be).

Comment: We do say that in the Bayesian approach. Data points are assumed independent conditional on the parameters. In the Frequentist approach, model parameters are not random variables so there's no conditioning on them and the independence assumption refers to the distribution of the data, which involves unknown parameters.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks !